# Linq, how to write regular query with aggregate function?

Tags: linq, aggregate-functions, aggregate

on my page, I need to show a list of tools.

var tools = _toolRepository.GetAll().Where(t => t.IsActive == true).OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate).Take(50).ToList();

I also need to show how many Votes each tool got, I can write a separate query to do that, but that will double the number of queries.

is there a way to combine them together?

here's my database structure.

### Tool

id

name

postDate

### ToolVote

id

ToolId

UserId

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var tools = _toolRepository.GetAll().Where(t => t.IsActive == true).OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate).Take(50).Select(tool => new { Tool = tool, votes = ToolVotes.Where(tv => tv.ToolID == tool.ToolID)} ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have 1 to * relationship you can use left join.

I can't test this query but it should look something like this

```
var query = (from tool in _toolRepository.GetAll().Where(t => t.IsActive == true).OrderByDescending(t => t.PostDate).Take(50)
             join toolVote in toolVotes on tool.id equals toolVote.ToolId
             into toolsTemp
             from toolTemp in toolsTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new { Tool = tool, Count = toolTemp == null ? 0 : toolTemp.Count})
            .ToList();
```